# how to get build failure reason in email content of Jenkins jobs

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have configured Jenkins job for gradle build making and also configured email ext plugin.Now i want when build fails, the build failure reason should be mentioned in email content along with build log attachment. Kindly let me know how to do this.

Comment: Why you don't want just attach a build log to the email ?

Answer (score 1):

Email ext can accept e-mail body content from a variable. In combination with [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) one can make a very detailed e-mail with a good structure.

You can achieve this by doing the following:

At each step that you want to record ( for example at some possible warning message in a build, or after each important step ) - write something to the file in build workspace. You can start at the beginning of a build with example:

```
rm -f email_preparation.txt # remove the preious run e-mail file;
echo "Hi,<br><br> This is an automatic e-mail from Jenkins regarding foo.<br>" > email_preparation.txt
```

Then append something:

```
echo "There were some warning during compilation of project 'bar'" >> email_preparation.txt
```

After the build run read the file to a variable and inject it with EnvInject:

```
echo "MAIL="`cat ${WORKSPACE}/email_preparation.txt` > ${WORKSPACE}/env.txt
```

Finally, simply add ${MAIL} to e-mail body. Don't forget to make use of html formatting.

Comment: Please elaborate, if possible provide step by step procedure as i am new to Jenkins and coding.

Comment: SO is not a resource to get programs/scripts written for free. The above instructions are an exhaustive guide to what you are trying to accomplish. The only way to elaborate it further is to make the implementation.

Comment: Alright, is there any other solution or way to accomplish this task